# Why not resend email confirmation email at the point of failed sign-in? (vs force a button press)

Tags: account-security

Assuming an app/website where email confirmation is required before logging in:

If newly registered user tries to sign in, a common flow is to tell them they are have not confirmed their email address yet and then ask if they want to re-send email confirmation, which is a two step process.

Is there are security concerns for just sending another confirmation email (with link) as soon as they try and fail to sign in?

People could end up being spammed but I doubt significantly more than they would in the other flow if someone was trying to be malicious.

Comment: Could be more of a UI thing: showing the address that they've entered could be a reminder that they used a different address to sign up, or have typoed the address (put gmial instead of gmail, or something like that). In that case, the user doesn't actually need a new email, just to enter the correct details. Depends on the specific flow you're using though.

Comment: In this scenario we'd 100% know the user exists, hasn't confirmed the associated email and *someone* is trying to sign in by putting in that email address. I hadn't considered anyone would sign-up with an invalid email address, in which case it'd be easier for them to re-register correctly and the likelihood they'd make the same typo on register and login is pretty low?

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, yes, there are some security concerns. The email link grants the *recipient* access to the account. If the user entered the wrong email, then by automatically sending the activation link again, you offer the unauthorised recipient another chance to take over the account.

If the user lost control over their email account, then the same problem applies.

In general, you want to give users positive control whether access-granting actions are performed.

Also, given that many "schroeders" mistakenly use my email address to sign up for things, I'm glad for non-automatic re-sending of activation emails. I get enough manually triggered email activation links for things I never signed up for ...

Comment: Ok we can agree email links ALWAYS grants the recipient access to the account, which is kinda the point for forgotten password etc. How would an unauthorised recipient get into an account if you re-send an activation link to the email address? If a user loses control over their email address, they'd have bigger problems and this argues with the whole concept of email validation which was not the scope of the question.

Comment: please read my scenario again: if the user types in the wrong email address. I get activation links all the time. If I click them, then *my* email is associated with the account, which means that I can complete registration or later trigger password resets.

Comment: which is already true, if I have your email address I can register you to loads of websites and you would have access to all of those accounts

Comment: hold on, you are not seeing the problem: if you are signing up *yourself* to something legitimate, but mistakenly type in *my email address*. It's not a spam thing, it's thinking that you are signing yourself up, but I control the email communciations.

Comment: For example, I mistakenly clicked an activation link for a service that I had already signed up for, but it was someone else who had created the new account for themselves. That account is now locked in with my email account as the primary. I have full access to everything in his account (he knows this and I forward on emails destined for him).

Comment: that is true of facebook/twitter/linked-in/tesco groceries... you would get the the confirmation email then able to do a password reset (via email) then it would be your account completely. This is true of practically every website

Comment: exactly - what's your point now?